# Solve: $x^3=0.5625$

Tags: logarithms

Solve: $x^3=0.5625$

$$x^3=0.5625/\log_3$$
$$\log_3x^3=\log_3 0.5625$$
$$3\log_3 x=\log_3 0.5625$$
$$\log_3 x=\frac{\log_3 0.5625}{3}$$

How to evaluate $\log_3 0.5625$?

How to change basis in logarithms for simplicity?

For example, if we have $\log_3 0.5625$, how to convert this logarithm such that the basis is not $3$, but $10$ (on my calculator, I only have $10$ as a basis)?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to involve logarithms in this? All you need to do is take the cube root.

Comment: Why do you want to use base $3$? Base $10$ works as well, but $\sqrt[3]{0.5625}=0.82548181222365667096865248810227$ would be easier.

Comment: Why not simply $\;x=\sqrt[3]{0.5625}\;$ ? You're going to use a calculator, anyway: what in the world do you need to mess up with logarithms for?

Comment: @Sebastian Schoennenbeck, because we can't calculate third root directly. We can calculate second and fourth root, and than aproximate third root.

Comment: @DonAntonio, Yes but my calculator can calculate only even roots (2,4,...).

Comment: @user7920621 Can't you do $\sqrt[3]{0.5625}=0.5625^{1/3}$ with your calculator? What calculator model do you have?

Comment: You can simply search 0.5625^(1/3) in Google.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the formula $$\log_a(x) =\frac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(a)}$$ where $a, b$ are positive numbers. In your case these are 3 and 10.

Comment: What is the base for logarithm in numerator?

Comment: You can choose that freely.

Comment: Yes i should have clarified. My apologies.

Comment: So, we can freely choose $a,b$?

Comment: Yes, as long as they are positive and not equal to 1.

Comment: @NDewolf, I get $\log_3 x=\frac{\log_{10}x}{\log_{10}3}=\frac{\log_{10}x}{0.48}$. From here, how to evaluate $x$?

Comment: That expression is equal to the right hand side of the formula in your question, which you can calculate in the same way. Then you can isolate the $\log_{10}(x)$ factor and invert the formula to obtain $x$.